# Blank value in Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to calculate the quotient of the cells in E and D rows, the logic is if both cells contains valid values then calculate otherwise do not do anything.

So far this is my formula:

```
={"OR (Open Rate)";ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(E2:E/D2:D))}
```

This works fine as it doesn't add value to the cell. But when I use the **getLastRow()** function on script editor, I get almost the 1000th cell on my empty sheet.

I suspect that the formula I am using is inserting a space or falsey values on each cell. How can I leave the cell blank if it doesn't meet my logic expression?

Comment: Shouldn’t the IFERROR function wrap the ARRAYFORMULA and not the other way around? If ARRAYFORMULA is the 1st parameter of IFERROR, you can set the empty string (“”) as the 2nd parameter. In this case, it’ll output empty string if an error occurs. Perhaps I’m missing something

Comment: @AntonDementiev My formula and the one you suggesting leads the same result, I don't want to set the cell an empty string nor any falsey value, I want to leave it blank. But the answer bellow seems to worked for me, thanks btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
={"OR (Open Rate)";ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(E2:INDEX(E2:E,COUNTA(E2:E))/D2:INDEX(D2:D,COUNTA(E2:E))))}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly.

@GGO I made a research and found these helpful links [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en), [COUNTA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093991?hl=en).